# Why '\A' in python regex doesn't work inside [ ]?

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to get a regex which would match a word in the beginning of the line or after certain word. I tried:

```
r"[\A|my_word](smth)"
```

But it failed because it doesn't match the \A in that case. What's wrong with that?

It turns out that \A doesn't work inside **[]**:

```
In [163]: type(re.search(r"\A123", "123"))
Out[163]: <type '_sre.SRE_Match'>

In [164]: type(re.search(r"[\A]123", "123"))
Out[164]: <type 'NoneType'>
```

But I don't understand why.

I'm using Python 2.6.6

**EDIT**:
After some comments I realized that the example I used with **[\A|my_word]** is bad. The actual expression is **[\AV]** to match either beginning of the string or V. The main problem I had is that I was curious why **[\A]** doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html, Do you've any idea what does `[]` do?

Comment: @stema: Yes, it an *anchor*, not a character class. You cannot use anchors inside a `[..]` character class and expect it to still be a treated as an anchor. The same goes for `^` and `$`, for example. You *can* include `\d` in a character class because that represents a character class (of digits).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sorry but I understood from your comment, that you don't know the meaning of `\A`. I know that zero width assertions can not be added to a char class.

Comment: @stema: No, sorry, I was trying to draw out the OP towards understanding this for themselves.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What is the reason for anchors being treated differently inside **[..]**?

Comment: @Phoenix: Because anchors are not characters. They don't match a specific character but a *position*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Anchors vs Character Classes

`\A` is an *[anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)* that matches a *position* in the string - in this case the position before the first char in the string. Other anchors are `\b`: word boundary, `^`: start of string/line, `$`: end of string/line, `(?=...)`: Positive lookahead, `(?!...)`: negative lookahead, etc. Anchors consume no characters and only match a position within the string.

`[abc]` is a *[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)* that always matches exactly one character - in this case either `a`, `b` or `c`

Thus, placing an anchor inside a character class makes no sense.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding of backslashes in bracket character classes was off, it seems, but even so, it is the case that `[\A|my_word]` is equivalent to `[A|my_word]` and will try to match a single one of `A`, `|`, `m`, `y`, `_`, `w`, `o`, `r`, or `d` before `smth`.

Here's a regular expression that should do what you want; unfortunately, a lookbehind can't be used in Python due to `\A` and `my_word` having different lengths, but a non-capturing group can be used instead: `(?:\A|abc)(smth)`.

(You can also use `^` instead of `\A` if you want, though the usage may differ in multiline mode as `^` will also match at the start of each new line [or rather, immediately after every newline] in that mode.)

Comment: I figured the way with non-capturing group, thank you. I'm now more interested in the reason for **[\A]** not to work. Using "|myword" was a bad idea for illustration as I can see now :) I unserstand that |,m,y.. are matched separately, but '\A' is not: **re.search(r"[\A]123", r"A123")** doesn't give a match

Comment: @Phoenix It gives a match for me. Are you sure you're testing it right?

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character in the brackets clauses loses its special meaning as escaping character.

I.e. in `[` `]` it will treat as two characters: `\` and `A`.

**[REF]**

Regex referencies:

[The Single UNIX Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/re.html)

[Python 2.6 - re module](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/re.html)

**UPDATE**

Bracket expression is special case iteself, thus that special sequences like `\A` (almost control commands for regex) will work there is very unlikely. It's somehow unnatural...

**ONE MORE THING**

As stated from `Python` reference:

> *(brackets)* Used to indicate a set of characters.

`\A` is special sequence which:

> Matches only at the start of the string.

It is obviously not a character of any set, I know `\n` NEWLINE, but I've never heard about STARTLINE (maybe pretty one).

**Also, for escapists:**
You could even put `]` into bracket without escaping it, if it comes right after the starting `[` left bracket:

> The pattern []] will match ']', for example.

Comment: `\\` is also in a character class the escape character, it allows you to add e.g. `]` and `-` to the class ==> `[abc\-\]]`. `\A` is an unknown escape sequence inside a char class and it does just evaluate to `A`.

Comment: @stema, yes you're right, it is also possible to escape `]` bracket, "exception that proves the rule" :)

Comment: @stema I think `-` versus `\-` only makes a difference when it's between two other characters, though, but that may just be because of how (unknown) escape sequences are interpreted.

Comment: No that is not an exeption. There are also the predefined classes that needs escaping and if you want to add the backslash as character you have to escape it `[\\abc\d\w\s\-a-c]`

Comment: @JAB; some prefer to escape the `-` inside a char class for better readability/clarity. I do put it at the start or the end.

Comment: All predefined classes are noted in the reference and skilled persons already see it as one symbol :) anyroad, allmost all characters in bracket expression considered as single characters that the difference. Also `'` single quoted string treated as `raw` without backslash character escaping, except the case of escaping `'` apostrophe itself.

Answer (score 1):

`[\A]` matches a single character that is either a `\` or an `A`. This is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: More likely, it only matches `A`.

Comment: It doesn't match any of them: **re.search(r"[\A]123", r"A123")** is not a match and **re.search(r"[\A]123", r"\123")** is not a match